# JavaScript reoccurrence replace innerHTML

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm trying to replace characters in html body. I have given id for the P tags.

**java script**

```
 function myFunction()
{
 var str=document.getElementById("branch").innerHTML; 
 var n=str.replace("rw","somesymbol");
 var n=str.replace("er","somesymbol");
 var n=str.replace("im","somesymbol");
 document.getElementById("branch").innerHTML=n;
}
```

**HTML code**

```
 <button onclick="myFunction()">replace</button>

 <p id="branch"> contents </p>
 <p id="branch"> contents </p>
 <p id="branch"> contents </p>
 <span class="s1"><img src="image.jpg"></span>
 <p id="branch">contents</p>
```

I have several paragraphs with id "branch". My problem is when I click on replace button, it does replace only on the first paragraph and doesn't go through the whole page. I was trying to remove the whole P tag from the body and keep just only paragraph tag for the whole content, in such case my image tags getting messed up, because of I'm replace few english characters to symbols.

hope you experts can help me. thanks

Thanks peter & Neiljun

Unfortunately the following doesn't work. I tried my best to google the solution. Still I'm not getting the right script.

**New java script**

```
 function myFunction()
{ 
 var str=document.getElementByClassName("branch").innerHTML;
 var n=str.replace("rw","somesymbol");
 var n=str.replace("er","somesymbol");
 var n=str.replace("im","somesymbol");
 document.getElementByClassName("branch").innerHTML=n;
}
```

**New HTML code**

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script src="file.js"></script>

 <button onclick="myFunction()">replace</button>

 <div class="demo">nfhry ehL. tsik kpFe;j ,e;jf; nfhry ehl;od; jiyefuk;</div>
 <div class="demo">mnahj;jp vd;w jpUefuhFk;. ,e;efuj;jpy; thGk; kf;fs; kwe;Jk; jP';F</div>
 <span class="s1"><img src="image.jpg"></span>
```

Comment: Javascript is NOT Java. Edited to change tag, and Blender got the title.

Comment: The `id` attribute is meant to be unique. You should not have multiple elements with the same `id`. That's what `class` is for.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery, and the class attribute. That way what you will have to do is simply
$('.branch').forEach( ... )

Comment: Thanks peter & Neiljun Unfortunately the class didn't work. I tried my best to google the solution. Still I'm not getting the right script.

Answer (score -1):

Blender is right - You can use `class` instead.  This will run throughout your paragraph. Replace `id` with `class`.

Comment: Thanks peter & Neiljun

Unfortunately the class didn't work. I tried my best to google the solution. Still I'm not getting the right script.